# Como saber el tiempo específico?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo saber el tiempo exacto en el cual estaba el setInterval al llamar a una función?

```js
var a = function() {

setInterval(function(){

// return this.time; 

},3600000);

};
```

Como podría saber cuando llame a `a()`, en que tiempo esta el `setInterval` y que me devuelva dicho valor?

Comment: Te refieres a la hora que tiene el navegador cuando inicia el setInterval, no?

Comment: No se puede obtener el valor de qué tiempo lleve un intervalo, no hay una propiedad de setInterval que te lo pueda regresar, tendrás que valerte de una función que lleve el tiempo que lleva el setInterval

Comment: @Rubén Ya lo he corregido, igual, no interfiere en la respuesta de lo que requiere el OP, gracias por avisar.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede saber el momento exacto en que estuvo en cada punto poniendo

```
var t = new Date();
```

en el punto en que se quiere

### ejemplo

```
var a = function() {
    var t1 = new Date();
    setInterval(function(){
        var t2 = new Date();
        var contando=0;
        while(new Date().getTime()<t2.getTime()+1100){
            contando++;
        }
        var t3 = new Date();
        console.log('lanzó el setInterval en',t1);
        console.log('la función interna comenzó en',t2);
        console.log('la función interna terminó en',t3);
        console.log('incrementando la variable',contando,'veces');
    },2000);

};

console.log("Comenzando", new Date());

a();
```

En ese ejemplo se ve cómo se obtiene el punto en que se dispara el `setInterval` y los momentos internos en que comienza y termina la función que está dentro del `setInterval`.

Se puede ver una corrida en http://rextester.com/AZHL96353